# How would I import an Excel table into a Windows Phone 7 app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an Excel table that has a list of items with headers on the columns and then each row is a single piece of data. So I want each row of the Excel spreadsheet to be a row in the app. I have searched for a nice way on how to do this. I am new to Windows Phone development so any detailed explanations would be appreciated. I am open to any ideas. I have about 9 tables that I want to import into an app. I was thinking a horizontal pivot style application would work since it is just rows of text. Below is an example of what I mean by a row in an Excel spreadsheet.

Column1     Col2            Col3      Col4
Data1         Data2         Data3         Data4

Comment: Hi, can you give us some more information? Do you want to import the excel files on the phone itself? If so, how will you get them to the phone? Or do you plan to import them while you're building the app?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to work with excel files on the phone, but you can convert them to csv files and read them in.  Take a look at the [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28VS.95%29.aspx) class and the [WP7 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff626519%28VS.92%29.aspx) on how to read files.